# Google Earth Plugin Displays Blue Instead of Terrain After Zooming

Tags: google-earth-plugin

We have an app that uses the Google Earth API. Recently, a couple of our users have encountered a problem with the plugin where the screen will turn blue after zooming in a certain amount and no terrain will be displayed.  But the screen will return to normal once zooming out.  So far we've established that the issue doesn't seem to be specific to our app because the same behavior occurs on the Google Earth Plugin download page found here: http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html.  It also doesn't seem to be browser specific as the same behavior has been replicated in IE, Chrome and FireFox on the same affected machine.  The other thing we've found is that if the user is running either the 6.1 or 6.2 versions of the plugin, uninstalling it and reinstalling 5.2 resolves the problem. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and, if so, is there a solution other than asking users to downgrade to 5.2?

Thanks in advance,
--Anne

Comment: Based on mentioning IE, I assume this is Windows. Which version of Windows? Are seeing the same problem on other versions?

Comment: It has only occurred on Windows machines but has happened in both XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Try go to Tools-Options-3DView. Try to change Graphics Mode from DirectX to OpenGL. Restart the application.
That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem just now.  Earlier today it was not doing this.  I wonder if there is a server problem with Google.  I will try finding an earlier version of the google earth plugin and try your fix.  I am wondering if there is a newer version of the api that is needed.

[Here](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40901) may be a helpful link from Google.

Also [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-earth-api-notify/topics).